# CherryPy shuts down unexpectedly

Tags: python, port, jupyter, cherrypy, fitbit

I am trying to implement a Jupyter Notebook python exercise and I see that 
i get these notes once i run this:

```
server = Oauth2.OAuth2Server(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
server.browser_authorize()
ACCESS_TOKEN = str(server.fitbit.client.session.token['access_token'])
REFRESH_TOKEN = str(server.fitbit.client.session.token['refresh_token'])
auth2_client = fitbit.Fitbit(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, oauth2=True, access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN, refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN)
```

i saw various solutions but none is applicable, perhaps i am missing something obvious. your help is highly appreciated...i use python 3 and i am running the Jupiter in virtual env of anaconda...

this is the response in the Jupiter.

```
[15/Oct/2018:20:35:55] ENGINE Listening for SIGTERM. [15/Oct/2018:20:35:55] ENGINE Bus STARTING CherryPy Checker: The Application mounted at '' has an empty config.

[15/Oct/2018:20:35:55] ENGINE Set handler for console events. [15/Oct/2018:20:35:55] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'. [15/Oct/2018:20:35:55] ENGINE Serving on http://127.0.0.1:8080 [15/Oct/2018:20:35:55] ENGINE Bus STARTED

127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2018:20:35:57] "GET /?code=72a3a2487757c76b0a07eb37a9c1b915fd69166a&state=D5RsnrJ0HnHD7N3mxYCuL6ZkbUnrB6 HTTP/1.1" 200 122 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134"

[15/Oct/2018:20:35:58] ENGINE Bus STOPPING [15/Oct/2018:20:36:07] ENGINE HTTP Server cherrypy._cpwsgi_server.CPWSGIServer(('127.0.0.1', 8080)) shut down [15/Oct/2018:20:36:07] ENGINE Stopped thread 'Autoreloader'. [15/Oct/2018:20:36:07] ENGINE Removed handler for console events. [15/Oct/2018:20:36:07] ENGINE Bus STOPPED [15/Oct/2018:20:36:07] ENGINE Bus EXITING
```

Answer (score 1):

In the context of https://github.com/orcasgit/python-fitbit / https://python-fitbit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ CherryPy is only used as 
a component to handle the OAuth2 interaction to generate a token.

The important object is:

```
auth2_client = fitbit.Fitbit(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, oauth2=True, access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN, refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN)
```

Just ignore the CherryPy log or if you *really* care about it, then configure the logger, but in terms of the goal of using the fitbit api it should be irrelevant unless the client is not able to negotiate the token.

Comment: thank you cyraxjoe - - - i used my (CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET) initially, getting data that is correct and validated. BUT now i am trying to repeat the exercise with a friend's ones (CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)  but the data i am getting it is still related to mine... this means 'the client is not able to negotiate the token' - is there a solution for that? thank you!

Comment: Those two are used to generate a token for the session. See the diagram in http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2016/01/22/understanding-oauth2/#Basic_knowledge

Comment: have a look at this @cyraxjoe:

Answer (score 0):

```
(MineFitbit) C:\Users\stelios ioannides\Documents\TT_Fitbit\python-fitbit>python gather_keys_oauth2.py [OAuth 2.0 Client ID] [Client Secret]

[24/Oct/2018:22:17:18] ENGINE Listening for SIGTERM.
[24/Oct/2018:22:17:18] ENGINE Bus STARTING
[24/Oct/2018:22:17:18] ENGINE Set handler for console events.
CherryPy Checker:
The Application mounted at '' has an empty config.

[24/Oct/2018:22:17:18] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.
[24/Oct/2018:22:17:18] ENGINE Serving on http://127.0.0.1:8080
[24/Oct/2018:22:17:18] ENGINE Bus STARTED
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Oct/2018:22:18:28] "GET /?code=a0c69fd0ba0e891f3ca223c7455015e29ad32c26&state=sZbyzbohIWntkp4mXPJTAFGDrlHnzV HTTP/1.1" 200 122 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134"
[24/Oct/2018:22:18:29] ENGINE Bus STOPPING
[24/Oct/2018:22:18:39] ENGINE HTTP Server cherrypy._cpwsgi_server.CPWSGIServer(('127.0.0.1', 8080)) shut down
[24/Oct/2018:22:18:39] ENGINE Stopped thread 'Autoreloader'.
[24/Oct/2018:22:18:39] ENGINE Removed handler for console events.
[24/Oct/2018:22:18:39] ENGINE Bus STOPPED
[24/Oct/2018:22:18:39] ENGINE Bus EXITING
[24/Oct/2018:22:18:39] ENGINE Waiting for child threads to terminate...
[24/Oct/2018:22:18:39] ENGINE Bus EXITED
[24/Oct/2018:22:18:39] ENGINE Waiting for thread Thread-14.
You are authorized to access data for the user: stelios ioannides
TOKEN
=====

access_token = [eliminated for security]
expires_in = 28800
refresh_token = [eliminated for security]
scope = ['activity', 'location', 'weight', 'profile', 'heartrate', 'sleep', 'social', 'settings', 'nutrition']
token_type = Bearer
user_id = [eliminated for security]
expires_at = 1540437508.9480457

(MineFitbit) C:\Users\stelios ioannides\Documents\TT_Fitbit\python-fitbit

**AS you can see I entered another person's credentials and i still get MY data...WHY?** the user stelios is ME...Why is this happening?
```

Comment: is this normal? - - - @cyraxjoe, i do not think so... my friends register his app as client one is that a mistake? under the "OAuth 2.0 Application Type"

Comment: All of that is correct. What do you want it to do? Maybe there lays the misunderstanding. You friend's client id and secrets, allows him (the client application) to have access to YOUR data, because you are the one that authenticate itself against the fitbit server. The client can you use your data to show you extra functionality based on the information now available to him (the cilent) and the important part WITHOUT THE NEED FROM HIM (the cilent, your friend) to ever know you password or have the possibility to see it.